Next js Api call, how to get response as a stream
I hace a small project on next js. It uses API call to get data as chunks, but the problem is that get the data as single response thought it is sent as chunks. Moreover Next js receives it as chunks, but does do anything until it gets all the chunks.
const useChating = () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
    const [response, setResponse] = useState('');
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const [chat_id, setChat_id] = useState(null);

    const submitChat = async (ChatData) => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        setResponse('');
        setError(null);

        try {
            const fetchResponse = await fetch('/api/chating', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify(ChatData),
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                },
            });

            if (!fetchResponse.ok) {
                throw new Error('Failed to get response from the server');
            }

            const reader = fetchResponse.body.getReader();
            const decoder = new TextDecoder();
            let receivedData = '';

            while (true) {
                const { done, value } = await reader.read();
                if (done) break;
                receivedData += decoder.decode(value, {stream: true});


                const lines = receivedData.split('\n');
                for (let i = 0; i < lines.length - 1; i++) {
                    try {
                        const line = lines[i];
                        const json = JSON.parse(line);
                        if (json.chat_id) {
                            setChat_id(json.chat_id);
                        } else if (json.message) {
                            setResponse(prev => [...prev, json.message]);
            }
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
                        setError('Failed to parse response data.');
                        break;
                    }
                }
                receivedData = lines[lines.length - 1];
            }
        } catch (fetchError) {
            console.error('Error during fetch:', fetchError);
            setError(fetchError.toString());
        } finally {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    };

    return { isLoading, response, error, chat_id, submit: submitChat };
};

export default useChating;

In this file if make console.log(chunk) after write(chunk) it gets chunks in real time not as single request. but useChatting gets it only when all chunks are ready and as single response.
export default async function handlerChat(req, res) {
    let body = { 
        ...req.body,
        rest 
    }
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        try {
            const fetchResponse = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/chat/', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(body),
            });
            if (!fetchResponse.ok) {
                console.error('Failed to fetch from Django backend');
                return res.status(fetchResponse.status).json({ error: 'Failed to fetch from Django backend' });
            }
            if (fetchResponse.ok) {
              }
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
            });
            if (fetchResponse.body.pipeTo) {
                const reader = fetchResponse.body.getReader();
                const stream = new ReadableStream({
                    async start(controller) {
                        while (true) {
                            const { done, value } = await reader.read();
                            if (done) break;
                            try {
                                controller.enqueue(value);
                            } catch (e) {
                                console.error("Error processing chunk", e);
                                controller.error(e);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        controller.close();
                        reader.releaseLock();
                    }
                });

                await stream.pipeTo(new WritableStream({
                    write(chunk) {
                        res.write(chunk);
                    },
                    close() {
                        res.end();
                    }
                }));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Fetch error:', error);
            res.status(500).end(JSON.stringify({ error: `Internal server error${error}` }));
        }
    } else {
        res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
        res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
    }
}

I don't know how to fix it

Have you checked https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#streaming ?

Yes, I checked the docx. But it did not help.
